# the problem of getSrcFilename() in R but not in littler

Tags: r, littler

I'd expect `getSrcFilename()` also works in `R` not just `lr`. Is it a bug in the command `R`?

```
$ lr -e "source('main.R');"
[1] "main.R"
$ R --slave --no-save --no-restore --no-init-file -e "source('main.R')"
character(0)
```

```
$ cat main.R 
options(keep.source=T)

f=function() {
  getSrcFilename(f)
}

print(getSrcFilename(f))
```